# How to build a Camping trailer, and riding across country with it

Tags: touring, trailer, diy, touring-bikes

I'm trying to build a camping trailer for my vintage Schwin Le Tour. I want to ride my bike across country and camp in this the whole way. I was wondering if anyone has done this before, and if anyone has tips for building one! Id really appreciate it!!

Comment: Do you want a trailer that opens into a tent, or simply a trailer that will let you haul your camping gear?  A few folks have built built the former, but it's more of a gimmick than practical.  But there are many different styles of practical bike trailers that can be used for camping gear.

Comment: There are also tents that you can build around your bike as a support.

Comment: What do you mean by *cross country*? It could mean *across a country* such as the US or Australia using roads, or *across a region*, not using roads.

Comment: Save time, money and headache. Look around a bit for a used kid trailer for your bike. Most of them have plenty of room to hold camping kit, food, etc (Even a spare wheel if you are so inclined), and a few of them have zip over rainproof flaps.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't built a bike trailer but used a B.O.B. Yak for a trip from the UK down through Europe.  It was a great trailer and we were able to fit a large 2-man tent in there plus other stuff.  We also had front and back panniers.

See here:  http://www.bobgear.com/bike-trailers/yak

I now use a Burley D'Lite with 2 toddlers in it.  Even though you could fit more stuff in it than the B.O.B. I would be wary of getting the centre of gravity too high.

See here: http://www.burley.com/page_308/dlite-p308

The thing to bear in mind is that these companies have researched the handling, aerodynamics, load bearing, etc which is something that you'd need to consider.

For touring I'd say the Yak is the way to go as it is designed and built specifically for this use.

Edit: Also, bought trailers come complete with the things you need to attach it to your bike.